# How to execute browser method inside protractor custom locator?

Tags: protractor

I want to execute browser method inside the protractor custom locator like:

```
import {browser} from 'protractor';
 protractor.by.addLocator("demo",(selector: string) => {
   browser.executeScript('my script')
 });
```

This throws error like:

```
protractor_1 not defined.
```

Any help will be valuable.

Add on:  Let me know, if we can use async /await inside custom locator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is CLEARLY NOT in the code you posted.

Somewhere you're using `protractor_1`, which is not defined. Look for it in your code

Comment: Nope. actually, its coming for ts -> js conversion

Answer (score -1):

1. You have imported 'browser' but not the actual 'protractor'

> import { browser, protractor } from 'protractor';

2. *browser.executeScript* cannot be executed in the context of the browser.

"@param {Function|string} script. A script to be run **in the context of the browser**.

Follow up the documentation: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.addLocator

Comment: I want to execute a script in the browser itself. I want to exactly mimic browser.executeScript('function scriipt as string') inside the custom locator. any document method is available to do the same for me? any idea will help.

Comment: When you execute a scrit in the browser context, all commands that you can do are same as you manually open the console in dev tools.